# How to partition hard drive during arch installation so I don's loose my previous data and still be able to use my NTFS Partition?

Tags: arch-linux, partition

Right now I have 4 partitions swap, efi, ext4 and ntfs I can format all the partitions except ntfs. I want to keep ntfs partition separate so that even when i switch operating systems i don't have to worry about my data.

**Note:** I am not planning a dual boot system I just want to keep data separate for safety so that I don't have any problem later even if my OS crashes. Also I want to use my ntfs partition in arch. Thanks

Comment: What is your problem? You say you already have four partitions. They look good to me.

Comment: Should I mount my data partition to \home? If I do that later can I access those files in any other OS?